# Should I check if a text field has text and then clean it or directly clean it?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So the question is basically if to have

```
    getDriver().findElement(by).clear();
```

or to have

```
    String text = getDriver().findElement(by).getText();
    if (!text.equals(""))
        getDriver().findElement(by).clear();
```

and after that a sendKeys.

Note: Most of the times, the field is empty.

Comment: Why would it matter?

Comment: Performance / time wise?

Comment: Here we are getting text and comparing. The performance would still be no better since the element need to be found and scanned anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple math

```
getDriver().findElement(by).clear();
```

Costs as

```
getDriver().findElement(by).getText();
```

To the second line you add an `if` check and maybe `getDriver().findElement(by).clear();` anyway.

So just call `clear()` without a check.